# Error saving images to Parse: "request body stream exhausted"

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am having a problem uploading images to Parse. Things were working fine up to yesterday. My app isn't live yet I'm just testing, images are about 25kb and it's just a single image used for the user profile picture. Code is:

```
 //Save the image
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
            PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profile.jpg" data:imageData];
            [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                if(succeeded){

                    [userBank setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profilePic"];

                    [userBank saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                        if(succeeded){

                           NSLog(@"save done");
                           userBank = [PFUser currentUser];
                           user[@"profilePic"] = imageFile;
                           [userBank saveInBackground];

                        }

                        else{

                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                            handler(NO,YES,nil);
                        }


                    }];


                }

                else{

                    NSLog(@"image not saved %@",error);
                    handler(NO,YES,nil);
                }

            }];//End save image block
```

I am suddenly getting this error: ***request body stream exhausted, NSUnderlyingError=0x17ece150 "request body stream exhausted"***. Has anyone encountered this before and could give me some pointers to what might be happening here?

Comment: On what line do you get that error?

Comment: The final else, for saving the image to the Parse.com server

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong but I'm unsure, let me check the doc

Comment: Are you sure you're on decent internet connection and that parse is up and running smoothly? I'll be honest I've never seen this error but other posts suggest that it's more of a lag issue. :l

Comment: I think it was Parse. Started working again after about 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profile.jpg" data:imageData];
[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (succeeded) {
           userBank = [PFUser currentUser];
            user[@"profilePic"] = imageFile;
            [userBank saveInBackground];
        }
    } else {
         // Handle error
    }        
}];
```

Comment: Hey, I actually have that in my code, didn't put it in the question. It's the save image block that's failing and returning an error not the save userBank

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was either my connection or Parse, although I did try and reset my internet connection a number of times and it made no difference. Anyway after about 30 minutes it started working again. Just posting this incase someone else has the same issue. Parse doesn't seem that reliable...

Answer (score 0):

try this
This error Comes on IOS but you can use different approach
like change your code line in formdata where you appending the file

```
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
```

to the below line basically don't append the file control but use the base64 image data

var reader = new FileReader();

```
reader.readAsDataURL(opmlFile.files[0]);

reader.onload = function () {

var base64DataImg = reader.result;            

base64DataImg = base64DataImg.replace('data:'imagetype';base64,', '');      
formData.append("FileBase64Data", base64DataImg);
}
```

Regards
Anil